# 7 card no peek rules

Tags: rules, strategy

7 card no peek game.  Down to the last 2 players. Trips are showing, next player must beat trips. He turns over a full house. He goes to bet, but player with trips is out of money, but still has cards left to turn over. What do you do?

Comment: If you are playing with wilds are you allowed to change the wilds as the hand unfolds?

Answer (score 3):

If they have cards but no money left they're all in and thus the other player cannot bet more to make them fold. Whatever money was in the pot before the other player bet is all the money the person with trips can win. The player without any money left cannot be bet out of the hand.

Run the cards out and see who has the best hand, if trips person ends up having the best hand they win the money, otherwise the other player.